# Angular: build issue using service from another component

Tags: angular, jenkins

I have following structure for few angular components.

Component A has a service S defined inside its /lib/services and I have declared S in A's public_api.ts

> export * from './lib/services/my-s.service';

I have to use S in another component B which itself resides inside another library.
Stucture is as:

> MyLib->src->lib>components->B

In B's component.ts, I am importing S as:

> import {S} from "../../../../../A/src/lib/services/my-s.service";

But this gives error in build:

> File '..../projects/A/src/lib/services/my-s.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '....projects/MyLib/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

How to get it working?

Comment: Could you see your tsconfig.json file? Which is ```"rootDir": "."```, or ```"rootDir": "../"```,

Comment: I can see tsconfig.json in project root directory

Comment: Please share with me your tsconfig.json

Comment: Here is the example link https://github.com/annalen/example-library, try to use the following ways.